Simulating removing DC from existing DCs using DNS: solving error "The RPC server is unavailable"
When we promoting domain controllers we get a frustrating error:
Error getting the list of sites from the target environment: The wizard cannot gain access to the list of domains in the forest.
This condition may be caused by a DNS lookup problem.
The error is:
The RPC server is unavailable.

We have checked that:

using "repadmin", we can see that there are no replicating errors.
We have checked the ports between the server and "PDC emulator", no port error found. This includes port 53(DNS), 88(Kerbros), 135(RPC endpoint), 445(SMB).
Windows firewall is closed.
We captured a network trace between the server and "PDC emulator", using netsh, however, no DNS lookup problem found.

There are two questions remaining:

How to check RPC ports. It is not effective and practical to check every port in 49152-65535.
How to check if one of the other domain controllers is at fault.


We use the script in this blog to check RPC ports: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/testing-rpc-ports-with-powershell-and-yes-its-as-much-fun-as-it-sounds/
. It turned out that these ports are reachable (This is suggested by a network expert in customer's company).
We use the following method to test removing DC:

backup the DNS record on the "PDC emulator" using:

dnscmd /zoneexport example.com backup-example.com.txt
dnscmd /zoneexport _msdcs.example.com backup-msdcs.example.com.txt

These files will be stored at "C:\Windows\system32\dns" folder. Copy them to the same location as the problematic machine.

Restore them locally:

Run:
dnscmd /zoneadd example.com /primary /file backup-example.com.txt /load
dnscmd /zoneadd _msdcs.example.com /primary /file backup-msdcs.example.com.txt /load

Then change settings to use local DNS server.

Use this script to remove DC one by one and test again:

$ServerFQDN = "dc01-2019.exoip.local." #Keep the dot (.) at the end
$ServerHostname = "dc01-2019"
$IPAddress = "192.168.1.51"

$Zones = Get-DnsServerZone | Where-Object { $_.ZoneType -eq "Primary" } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ZoneName

foreach ($Zone in $Zones) {
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $Zone | Where-Object { 
        $_.RecordData.IPv4Address -eq $IPAddress -or
        $_.RecordData.NameServer -eq $ServerFQDN -or
        $_.RecordData.DomainName -eq $ServerFQDN -or
        $_.RecordData.HostnameAlias -eq $ServerFQDN -or
        $_.RecordData.MailExchange -eq $ServerFQDN -or
        $_.HostName -eq $ServerHostname
    } | Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $Zone -Force -WhatIf
}

Reference: https://www.alitajran.com/clean-up-dns-records-powershell/
It turned out that one of the DCs is at fault. When we demote that DC we are able to promote new domain controllers.
BTW,
Additional analysis showed that RPC is using port 445, and the fault DC's 445 port is not reachable.

Important logs to check: dcpromoui.log

analysis showed that RPC is using port 445. No that is not RPC. It's SMB. It says SMB in the bottom pane.
